# PySparck How to notify the number of nodes that I am going to use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark

I am learning how to use spark, but there are things I still don't understand. I have the following code

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/kddcup.data_10_percent.gz", "kddcup.data_10_percent.gz")

data_file = "./kddcup.data_10_percent.gz"
raw_data = sc.textFile(data_file)

normal_raw_data = raw_data.filter(lambda x: 'normal.' in x)
normal_raw_data

from time import time
t0 = time()
normal_count = normal_raw_data.count()
tt = time() - t0
print (("There are {} 'normal' interactions").format(normal_count))
print ("Count completed in {} seconds".format(round(tt,3))
```

I have already created my rdd, but supposedly Sparck works in parallel with multiple nodes. And in the code I don't see that at any time it clarifies the number of nodes in which I want to divide them, and the amount of memory that I'm going to use.

As you can see, I want to count the time it takes to process. To see the difference between working with Spark (and its parallel system) or working as I normally do with Pandas DataFrames

Answer (score 0):

> in the code I don't see that at any time it clarifies the number of nodes in which I want to divide them, and the amount of memory that I'm going to use

You ideally, wouldn't put that in the code, you would use `--num-executors` and `--executor-memory` arguments of `spark-submit`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

You could update `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS']` if you wanted to insert that into the code, though.

Note that if you do run that code as-is, every node will perform the same `urlretrieve` locally, and not fetch from a shared file location.